# How to concat two array / list columns of different spark dataframes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Need a concat dataframe. 
Columns from two different spark dataframes. 
Looking for pyspark code.

```
df1.show()
+---------+
|    value|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
+---------+

df2.show()
+------+
| value|
+------+
|[4, 5]|
+------+


I need a dataframe as bleow:
+------------+
| value      |
+------------+
|[1,2,3,4,5] |
+------------+
```

Comment: So what say there are more rows? Positional dependence?

Comment: Yes.Should concat only corresponding rows.

Comment: Bases on position?

Comment: yes Bases on position

Comment: Try zipwithindex

Comment: which version of spark?

Comment: Still need help?

Comment: to use zipwithindex i have to convert both dataframe to rdd and then add up the list ryt? is there any other option?

Comment: no that's about it as there no DS for pyspark if I remember. How wasy depends on what version of Spark u r running

Comment: Any progress? Which version Spark?

Comment: I don't want to use rdd option. I am using spark 2.4.  Dataframe.

Comment: So, you have solved using a DF only? I am not sure you can do that. If you have not  solved I will solve tomorrow,

Comment: I haven't solved it . I need it with DF

Comment: OK, I will solve it later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some educational aspects here as well, and you can strip out the .show(), some data generation first.

> Spark 2.4 assumed.
>   Positional dependency is OK although some dispute if it is preserved with RDDs and such with just zipWithIndex; I have no evidence to doubt that.
>   No performance considerations in terms of explicit partitioning, but no UDFs used.
>   Assuming same number of rows in both DFs. DataSet not a pyspark object.
>   Need rdd conversion.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([ list([[x,x+1,x+2]]) for x in range(7)], ['value'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([ list([[x+10,x+20]]) for x in range(7)], ['value'])
dfA = df1.rdd.map(lambda r: r.value).zipWithIndex().toDF(['value', 'index'])
dfB = df2.rdd.map(lambda r: r.value).zipWithIndex().toDF(['value', 'index'])

df_inner_join = dfA.join(dfB, dfA.index == dfB.index)
new_names = ['value1', 'index1', 'value2', 'index2']
df_renamed = df_inner_join.toDF(*new_names) # Issues with column renames otherwise!

df_result = df_renamed.select(col("index1"), concat(col("value1"), col("value2"))) 
new_names_final = ['index', 'value']
df_result_final = df_result.toDF(*new_names_final)
```

Data In (generated)

```
+---------+
|    value|
+---------+
|[0, 1, 2]|
|[1, 2, 3]|
|[2, 3, 4]|
|[3, 4, 5]|
|[4, 5, 6]|
|[5, 6, 7]|
|[6, 7, 8]|
+---------+

+--------+
|   value|
+--------+
|[10, 20]|
|[11, 21]|
|[12, 22]|
|[13, 23]|
|[14, 24]|
|[15, 25]|
|[16, 26]|
+--------+
```

Data Out

```
+-----+-----------------+
|index|            value|
+-----+-----------------+
|    0|[0, 1, 2, 10, 20]|
|    6|[6, 7, 8, 16, 26]|
|    5|[5, 6, 7, 15, 25]|
|    1|[1, 2, 3, 11, 21]|
|    3|[3, 4, 5, 13, 23]|
|    2|[2, 3, 4, 12, 22]|
|    4|[4, 5, 6, 14, 24]|
+-----+-----------------+
```